# Does Nodejitsu support neo4j?

Tags: node.js, neo4j, nodejitsu

I want to use Nodejitsu to host my Node.js app. The app also uses Neo4j. Does Nodejitsu provide any kind of support for that? Or do I need to host Neo4j separately (and pay for all network traffic)?

Comment: i seem to recall they used to use logstash for the infrastructure. not sure if you get this as part of the service. might be worth asking nodejitsu support directly.

Comment: What did you end up using?

Answer (score 3):

[Nodejitsu](http://nodejitsu.com/) doesn't support native Neo4j integration. If you can host a Neo4j service or find one you can use it, and for node.js applications you can use the neo4j api with https://github.com/thingdom/node-neo4j

I will try to find the best answer for you, if I can find anything about Neo4j hosting i will update this question.

Comment: Nodejitsu was bought by Godaddy a couple of years ago so I doubt this was ever implemented.